# Who planted the bomb under the stage in Bodyguard?

Tags: plot-explanation, bodyguard

Who placed the bomb under the stage that killed Julia Montague?

[image: Julia Montague on stage]

Comment: very much related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94276/was-it-just-coincidence-that-tahir-mahmood-went-on-stage